# Format a date stored as "text" to the pattern "mm-dd"

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, type-conversion

I want to change the `text` data type to "mm-dd" while extracting.

The column holds a date and data type is `text`.

Original data: `'Sat Aug 31 2013'`. I want this as `'8-31'`.

Comment: Never, ever store dates as strings. You should fix your data model before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(to_date(date_string_column_name, 'DY Mon DD YYYY'),'MM-YY')
```

Here you can look to date formating: [Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: How can i make this applicable for the entire column. Can you help me in this

Comment: What is the name of the column that contains the date string ?

Answer (score 1):

As [@a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800498/format-a-date-stored-as-text-to-the-pattern-mm-dd/20805060#comment31189820_20800498), the proper fix would be to convert your column to `date`. While stuck with your unfortunate design ...

`Sat` in the string `Sat Aug 31 2013` is redundant. Actually, [**`to_date()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) ignores it in this pattern. General Validity of 3-letter abbreviation is checked, then it's ignored. Could even be the wrong day. Faster to ignore it a priori. [I quote the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE):

> In `to_date`, `to_number`, and `to_timestamp`, double-quoted strings skip
>   the number of input characters contained in the string, e.g. "XX"
>   skips two input characters.

Also, to skip leading zeros (and whitespace) in the output like your example (`'8-31'`) suggests, use the [`FM` modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE).

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(date_col, '"XXX "Mon DD YYYY'),'FMMM-DD')
FROM   tbl
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8e821/1)